# How do I get "git log --name-only" in libgit2

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

In GitBash `git log --name-only -1` gives me:

```
commit e584beed88a9d005e7066c41b248545ae99f6c2b    
Author: Badgers Paw < noone@example.com >    
Date:   Thu Dec 1 13:39:03 2016 +0000    
    EEE-9245 - WIP
Components/BuildTools/BuildTasks.Test/Class1.cs
Components/BuildTools/BuildTasks.exe
Components/BuildTools/BuildTasks/Docs/README.txt
Components/BuildTools/BuildTasks/Program.cs
Components/BuildTools/BuildTasks/Tasks/Task1.cs
Components/BuildTools/BuildTasks/Tasks/Task2.cs
```

How can I get this in libgit2 or (ideally) libgit2sharp?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to run a diff to get the list of changed files. For the first log entry it would be `git_diff_tree_to_tree` between the HEAD commit and it's parent. After you run the diff you can ignore the rest of the information and print the name of the files only.

Answer (score 0):

Using libgit2sharp this is:

```
var parent = commit.Parents.Single();
{
    foreach (TreeEntryChanges change in repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(parent.Tree, commit.Tree))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(change.Path);
        }
    }
}
```